# How can I get a "RedLevel" instead of GrayLevel when drawing a densityplot?

Tags: plotting, color

I was trying different colorfunctions, but don't get the RedLevel like the picture as follow:[image]
My picture is like this, a greylevel one.
[image]

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the methods posted by KennyColnago, we also have `Blend`:

```
ArrayPlot[
 Table[Sin[x y],
  {x, -2, 2, 0.01},
  {y, -2, 2, 0.01}
  ],
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Red}, #] &)
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or with `Black` (because I think that this is an equivalently valid interpretation of `RedLevel`):

```
ArrayPlot[
 Table[Sin[x y],
  {x, -2, 2, 0.01},
  {y, -2, 2, 0.01}
  ],
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Black, Red}, #] &)
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I just made a grayredlevel one today with my advisor, nice!

Comment: One can also use `Lighter[]` or `Darker[]` for this, e.g. `ArrayPlot[Table[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.01}], ColorFunction -> (Lighter[Red, 1 - #] &)]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
redWhiteTones = RGBColor[1, #, #] &;
whiteRedTones = RGBColor[1, 1 - #, 1 - #] &;
blackRedTones = RGBColor[#, 0, 0] &;
redBlackTones = RGBColor[1 - #, 0, 0] &;

Row[ArrayPlot[Table[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.01}], 
      ColorFunction -> #, PlotLabel -> Style[#, Black, 20], ImageSize -> 300] & /@ 
  {redWhiteTones, whiteRedTones,  blackRedTones, redBlackTones}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

This is an alternative way to get the colors produced by `Blend` in C.E.'s answer, For example:

```
redWhiteTones /@ Range[0, 1, .1] ==  Blend[{Red, White}, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]
```

> True

```
blackRedTones /@ Range[0, 1, .1] == Blend[{Black, Red}, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, .1]
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

If I use `ArrayPlot`, and make up some data, the grey level image looks like the following.

```
ArrayPlot[
    Table[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.01}],
          ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[#] &)]
```

[image: grey level image]

A corresponding red level image could be written like this.

```
ArrayPlot[
    Table[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.01}],
          ColorFunction -> (Directive[Opacity[1 - #], Red] &)]
```

[image: red level image]

Alternatively, use the full form of `Hue` as follows.

```
ArrayPlot[
    Table[Sin[x y], {x, -2, 2, 0.01}, {y, -2, 2, 0.01}],
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[1, 1 - #, 1] &)]
```

To reverse the colour scaling, replace 1-# with # in `ColorFunction`.